# Plot roc curve with R from two variables (factor): predicted vs. real

Tags: r, roc, confusion-matrix

I have in my data two columns, each with binary outcome "Yes", "No". One is the prediction (var_pred) and the other is the reality (var_real).
I have already perform a confussionMatrix with caret and have the sensitivity, specificity and AUC, but I need to plot a ROC curve. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Please show a sample of your data.

Comment: Have you tried the 'roc' function in pROC package?